# Wordpress Installation Wizard Does Not Appear

Tags: ftp, redhat-enterprise-linux, wordpress

I'm trying to run the WordPress Installation wizard on my dedicated server.

When I access the folder where WordPress is present, I get the FTP view.

Any Idea why is that? Phpmyadmin is working fine using the [IP]/phpmyadmin URL.

But I need to use // before the IP to be able to view it. If I directly use the URL, I get that the page is not Found

Can someone guide me? What should I tell the hosting company to fix?

[Browser view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShSwH.png)

Comment: I figured they are giving me hell every time I request something

Comment: Is there something specific to tell them tho so that its fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get anything when you to go http://111.222.333.444/gtaadmin/GTA/index.php ??

Without more information on your host configuration - I would guess that the most likely reason for this is that the default document type isnt specified.

A couple of options to resolve this are:

1) Get the default document of index.php added to the host

2) Create a redirect rule in htaccess (see https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)

You will want something like:

```
Redirect /path/to/old/file/ http://www.example.com/new/file/index.php
```

Comment: Hello! I get Not Found
The requested URL /gtaadmin/GTA/index.php was not found on this server. if I try to access anything present in the FTP. Is that an apache issue? I can only view html and other media files when I access the websites using file:// before the IP. When I access it that way and try accessing a php file, I see the code instead of running it

Comment: Sounds horribly apache config-y to me.  I'll bow out now as I'm not an apache guru by any means and wouldn't want to lead you down the wrong route - but if you can see a directory and not a file in it, there's not a vast number of things other than the serving application that it can be.  Have you tried WebMasters Stack Exchange?  There's Apache Guru's galore on there

Comment: Okay so I sent the team an email with visible anger in it and it did the trick, they got it fixed.

Comment: Glad its sorted - sorry I coudnt be more helpful in pinning down the specific issue